# Add title and alt attributes

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2

I would like to know if it would be possible to add title and alt attributes of a displayed image with Lightbox2, using title and alt attributes of `<a>` tag.

For instance :
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Original :

```
<img class="lb-image" src="images/image-2.jpg" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 640px;">
```

Modified :

```
<img class="lb-image" src="images/image-2.jpg" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 640px;" title="Optional caption." alt="Optional caption.">
```

Thanks
Dom

Comment: is the modified version the new edit after you made changes or what you looking to achieve?

Comment: Hi. The modified version is what I would like to have.